# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: at okhttp3.Headers$Builder.checkNameAndValue

Tags: java, android, facebook, react-native

I get this bug in Google console.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:    at
>   okhttp3.Headers$Builder.checkNameAndValue (Headers.java:320)   at
>   okhttp3.Headers$Builder.add (Headers.java:270)   at
>   com.facebook.react.modules.network.NetworkingModule.extractHeaders
>   (NetworkingModule.java:702)   at
>   com.facebook.react.modules.network.NetworkingModule.sendRequest
>   (NetworkingModule.java:330)   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
>   (Native Method)   at
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke
>   (JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)   at
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke
>   (JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)   at
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run (Native Method)
>   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:761)   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:98)   at
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage
>   (MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)   at android.os.Looper.loop
>   (Looper.java:156)   at
>   com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run
>   (MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)   at java.lang.Thread.run
>   (Thread.java:776)

[from google console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxmIe.png)

> Environment: OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.6 Node: 8.6.0 Yarn: 1.5.1 npm:
>   5.6.0 Watchman: 4.9.0 Xcode: Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235 Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4720617
>
> Packages: (wanted => installed) react: 16.3.1 => 16.3.1 react-native:
>   0.55.4 => 0.55.4

```
var DeviceInfo = require('react-native-device-info');
var deviceName = DeviceInfo.getDeviceName()
const apiLevel = DeviceInfo.getAPILevel()
const brand = DeviceInfo.getBrand()
const buildNumber = DeviceInfo.getBuildNumber()
const carrier = DeviceInfo.getCarrier()
const deviceCountry = DeviceInfo.getDeviceCountry()
const deviceLocale = DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale()
const manufacturer = DeviceInfo.getManufacturer();
const model = DeviceInfo.getModel();
const readableVersion = DeviceInfo.getReadableVersion();
const serialNumber = DeviceInfo.getSerialNumber();
const systemName = DeviceInfo.getSystemName();
const systemVersion = DeviceInfo.getSystemVersion();
const uniqueId = DeviceInfo.getUniqueID();
const version = DeviceInfo.getVersion();
const isTablet = DeviceInfo.isTablet();
const isEmulator = DeviceInfo.isEmulator();
export const getCode = async (phone) => await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${url}/api/mobile/external/code_send`,
    headers: {
        apiLevel,
        brand,
        buildNumber,
        carrier,
        deviceCountry,
        deviceLocale,
        deviceName,
        manufacturer,
        model,
        readableVersion,
        serialNumber,
        systemName,
        systemVersion,
        uniqueId,
        version,
        isTablet,
        isEmulator
    },
    data: {phone},
    timeout: 10000,
});
```

Comment: How's your code look like?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn My application falls right after the start and I do not understand why and what's the problem

Comment: How do you call the facebook API? You pass some illegal arguments

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn

`export const getCode = async (phone) => await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: `${url}/api/mobile/external/code_send`,
    headers: {
        apiLevel,
        brand,
        buildNumber,
        carrier,
        deviceCountry,
        deviceLocale,
        deviceName,
        manufacturer,
        model,
        readableVersion,
        serialNumber,
        systemName,
        systemVersion,
        uniqueId,
        version,
        isTablet,
        isEmulator
    },
    data: {phone},
    timeout: 10000,
});`

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn
`var DeviceInfo = require('react-native-device-info');
var   deviceName = cyrill_to_latin(DeviceInfo.getDeviceName())
const apiLevel = DeviceInfo.getAPILevel()
const brand = DeviceInfo.getBrand()
const buildNumber = DeviceInfo.getBuildNumber()
const isEmulator = DeviceInfo.isEmulator();`

Comment: This might help you [issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2802)

Comment: What were you trying to achieve, that led to this exception stack trace? Can you show some code ? Can you provide some details ?

Comment: @Manmohan_singh if I knew what the problem I would describe in more detail but I do not know. Maybe someone already saw this problem so I wrote this question.
 MạnhQuyếtNguyễn think problem in api

Comment: Don't put the code in comments, put it in your question. Tag the question [tag:javascript] if your code is in javascript.

Comment: @DavidConrad ok thanks